# Zebra dialogue js - trying to return a value false or true

Tags: javascript, boolean, confirm, zebra-ui-framework

I'm trying to return a value from a Zebra_Dialog framework. I need a value like true or false in order to send it as an input so I can update my store card.

The problem is that I'm able to do it with confirm (which return always a value like true or false, but I've no idea about how to do with a javascript framework with that structure.

My code so far was the following:

confirm():

```
$('#removebuttonstyle i').click(function() {
    console.log("you click!");
    var c = confirm("Are you sure that you want to continue?");
    return c;
});
```

zebra():

```
$('#removebuttonstyle i').on('click', function(e) {
    console.log("you click!");
    e.preventDefault();
    var t = $.Zebra_Dialog('<strong>Zebra_Dialog</strong>, a small, compact and highly configurable dialog box plugin for jQuery', {
      type: 'question',
      title: 'Custom buttons',
      buttons: ['Yes', 'No'],
      onClose: function(buttons) {
        if (buttons=='Yes') {
         return true;
       } else {
         return false;
       }
     }
   });
    return buttons;
  });
```

Like you can imagine, the zebra approach doesn't work. Any help? Someone who did that?

Update: I actually made some progress, so the last step is to reassign the value to true or false:

```
$('#removebuttonstyle i').on('click', function(e) {
    console.log("you click!");
    e.preventDefault();
    var t = $.Zebra_Dialog('<strong>Zebra_Dialog</strong>, a small, compact and highly configurable dialog box plugin for jQuery', {
      type: 'question',
      title: 'Custom buttons',
      buttons: [
      {caption: 'Yes'},
      {caption: 'No'}
      ],
      onClose: function(caption) {
        caption == 'Yes' ? true : false;
        console.log(caption);
      }
    });
  });
```

If I console.log caption I still obtain yes or not, but I need to reassign the value true or false to the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution:

```
$('#removebuttonstyle i').on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var t = $.Zebra_Dialog('<strong>Zebra_Dialog</strong>, a small, compact and highly configurable dialog box plugin for jQuery', {
        type: 'question',
        title: 'Custom buttons',
        buttons: [
        {caption: 'Yes'},
        {caption: 'No'}
        ],
        onClose: function(caption) {
          if (caption == 'Yes') {
            $("#removebuttonstyle i").unbind('click').click()
          } else {
            caption = false;
          }
          return caption;
        }
      });
    });
```